# segmentation-error in ubuntu gcc

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *ch;
    int n=10;
    gets(ch);
    puts(ch);
    printf("%d\n",n);

}   

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *ch;
    int n=10;
    gets(ch);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    puts(ch);

}
```

In the first one , the segmentation error occurs at print(n) and in second one it occurs at puts(ch).No error occurs if print(n) is also used just after declaring n.

Comment: @Scroll-lock Is it clear to you what `char *ch` does? Please read a tutorial, for example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ It will be a good time investment

Comment: @Scroll-lock With this approach, it will be the first error out of many. You cannot use pointers without knowing what a pointer is. Below you have answers to this specific problem. What you are doing in your program is like buying a house without a terrain where to put it. You have first to allocate memory.

Answer (score 7):

`gets()` is dereferencing an unitialized pointer, causing [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Allocate memory for `ch` and don't use [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) as there is no way to limit the number of characters read, meaning potentially writing beyond the bounds of the destination array.

Example using [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

```
char ch[128];
if (fgets(ch, 128, stdin))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fgets and allocate memory for your "buffer" (via malloc) to hold the given string. At the end call free for your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    int main(){
        char * ch = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
        //or by using this: char ch[10];
        int n=10;
        gets(ch);
        puts(ch);
        printf("%d\n", n);
        free(ch);
}
```